# Как разделить (скопировать и переименовать) файл в несколько в Tortoise GIT?

Tags: git, tortoise-git

В репозитории git есть файл с тремя большими классами (классА, классБ и классВ), который был создан несколько лет назад, рос и разрастался. Сейчас пришло время разделить этот файл на три отдельных - файлА, файлБ и файлВ, с соответствующим классом внутри каждого из них. При этом необходимо, чтобы в каждом из новых файлов была сохранена его история изменения до момента разделения.

Я хочу разделить 1 файл на 3, для этого я хочу скопировать его (сделать 2 копии с новыми именами) и повырезать в каждой копии лишний части. Чтобы в итоге в каждом из трех файлов сохранилась история до их разделения.

Как это сделать средствами TortoiseGIT ?

P.S. В Tortoise SVN такая опция есть. При перетаскивании файла правой кнопкой мыши, в меню есть пункты "SVN Copy here" "SVN Copy and Rename here ..".

Comment: если вопрос исключительно про функционирование программы tortoisegit (в неизвестной операционной системе), то метка `git`, по-моему, явно лишняя.

Comment: Если в TortoiseGit решения нет, то придется в git ...

Comment: `git` «такого» явно не умеет: оно ему ни к чему. скопировать и отредактировать файл можно, пожалуй, в **любой** операционной системе, понимающей такую абстракцию, как «файл».

Comment: *придется в git* — я о том и говорю: вопрос не имеет отношения ни к программе git, ни к протоколу, им используемому, ни к формату хранилища… в общем, ни к чему, связанному с термином «git».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Дополнил вопрос, прочитайте пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению передать эти сведения в git невозможно.

Git оперирует состоянием всего репозитория и его версиями во времени, но не изменениями приведшими к этим версиям. Эвристика изменений полностью на стороне программ для работы с git.

Таким образом вопрос лишен смысла, т.к. это задача программ для работы с git определить, что три новых файла были созданы из 1 старого.

Вывод: копируем файлы средствами ОС, добавляем их в git, коммитим. Дальше задача программ разобраться что к чему (у Git Blame получается, а у TortoiseGit - не всегда).

Comment: Вы в итоге вручную решали задачу? Посмотрел на свой ответ... надо бы хоть ради академического интереса написать этот скрипт.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Решать ничего не пришлось, как описано в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, можно сделать скрипт, последовательно обрабатывающий все коммиты в истории:

1. Получаем актуальную версию файла

   ```
   cd path/to/old/repo
   git checkout <rev-number>
   lastmessage = $( git log --pretty=format:'%s' | head -n 1)
   author = $( git log --pretty=format:'%an' | head -n 1)
   date = $( git log --pretty=format:'%ad:' | head -n 1)
   ```
2. По границам классов разбиваем его на три. Пишем их в отдельную папку поверх тех, что там уже есть (вне этого репозитория). Например, через `sed` можно их делить.

   ```
   somecommand bigfile path/to/new/repo
   ```
3. В той папке делаем

   ```
   cd path/to/new/repo
   git add file1 file2 file3
   # если изменений в файле не было, то и добавлять нечего

   git commit -m'$lastmessage' --author=$author --date=$date;
   # предполагаю, что сообщение соответствующего коммита описывает,
   # в каком из классов было изменение и в чем оно состоит.
   ```
4. Коммит++, к шагу 1.

Осталось написать `somecommand`, которая разделит ваш файл. Если дадите какой-нибудь пример, как у вас границы классов выглядят, попробую сделать.

Еще проблема в том, что переносятся не все данные. По-хорошему, нужно переносить всё, включая author-mail, commiter-name, commiter-mail...

А еще нужно придумать способ перелистывать коммиты в обратном порядке.